# I want to detect latin characters with umlaut mark anywhere in given string by using informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, data-quality

I want to detect latin characters with umlaut mark anywhere in given string by using informatica. 
Requirement is whenever I found atleast one Latin character with umlaut mark anywhere in a string, I'll give output as Fail else pass.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function:

**REG_MATCH** : Returns whether a value matches a regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
REG_MATCH ( column, pattern ) provides you the proper result.
```

Go through below link for more on regular expressions. 
https://marketplace.informatica.com/mpresources/docs/RegularExpressions_2255.pdf 
http://www.disoln.org/2012/12/Data-Cleansing-and-Standardization-Using-Regular-Expression-informatica-powercenter.html